# How do I rotate many objects with each object as its own anchor?

Tags: inkscape

I have a bunch of incorrectly rotated objects, like this:

[image]

I want to rotate them all at once so that they are all upright, like this:

[image]

The only way I know how to do this is by selecting and rotating each object individually, which is tedious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object > Transform dialog has option "Apply to each object separately". Use it.