# Where is the Object tab and how do I rotate many objects with each object as its own anchor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, rotate

Someone had a similar problem a year ago and this question was already asked and answered regarding *Inkscape* by someone else a year ago. [Here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134251/how-do-i-rotate-many-objects-with-each-object-as-its-own-anchor).

The problem is that I'm such a noob on **Photoshop** that I don't understand the previous answer for Inkscape.

**Can I perform "Object > Transform - Apply to each object separately" in Photoshop?**

And especially, what does "Object" mean and where is it?

I don't have any "Object" tab/option in my left-hand corner toolbar and neither in my lateral (left-center) toolbar.

Can someone provide me a screenshot of where it is?

I need to rotate a series of individual layers around their own centers - a "transform each" type of operation in **Photoshop**.

Comment: I'm uncertain what's happened here. It looks like you've merely posted a screenshot from your other question.  [How do I rotate many objects with each object as its own anchor?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/134251/how-do-i-rotate-many-objects-with-each-object-as-its-own-anchor) There's no need to add the answer to a *new* question.

Comment: @Scott he's asking how to carry out the answer

Comment: Not it's not my question, someone else posted that question. I just commented it. I just don't understand what is the "Object" toolbar and where is it? That's all I need to know

Comment: Ahh I missed that it was two separate users, sorry. I clarified. @Ireallyneedhelp realize the question you refer to is using **Inkscape** and not Photoshop. Photoshop does not have an "object" menu.

Comment: @Ireallyneedhelp check here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17298/resize-multiple-layers-around-their-respective-anchor-points

Comment: .. and thanks @ZachSaucier for pointing out my oversight `:)`